# How to schedule cron job from shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to schedule a cron job in Linux by running a shell script.

The scenario is, I'm taking the time in HH:MM format in the shell script from the user and want to schedule a cron job from the shell script. I even want the cron job to be executed only once.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Maybe use `at` if it is a one-off. Try `man at`.

Comment: what I want is rather than scheduling crontab by using "crontab -e" and writing the command eg."30 08 10 06 * /home/full-backup", I want to execute the same using a shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `crontab`, you can do something like this:

```
cur=$(crontab -l)
new="$mm $hh * * * your_command"

echo "$cur$new" | crontab -
```

For one-shot, crontab is not the good candidate. Use `at` (note: your_command must be a file, e.g., a bash script)

```
at -f your_command $hh:$mm
```